# What's happening with this users account links?

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-accounts, per-site-meta

I was looking at a puzzle on the [Puzzling riddle sandbox](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5276/the-riddle-sandbox/5347#5347), and I clicked on the user. This what I clicked on:

[image: user]

That brought me [here](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/29437/user29437):

[image: metaprofile]

Note the rep difference.

Then I clicked in 'Main user', and I got a [page not found](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/29437/user29437):

[image: pagenotfound]

So I went back to the Meta profile, and clicked on the Puzzling thingy on the accounts, and got [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/29457/rsp):

[image: rsp]

(Sorry, don't know what happened with my screenshot.)

It can't be the name difference in the URL, because SE accounts for that, last I saw. So what's happening here?

Comment: [This](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/29437/user29437) is the meta-user, and if you look at the top network posts, [this](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/29457/rsp) is the corresponding main user.

Comment: It'd be so cool if there was a puzzle hidden in all of this. Especially with the fourth photo being a different tint, but that might just be f.lux

Comment: @Areeb Nope, sorry. It would be posted on the main site if it was a puzzle :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that the user account was merged and that the merge didn't fully set through to his/her meta account (since account information is synced periodically).

As you can see, there are two user accounts involved, but referenced on the meta user profile:

https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/29457/rsp

And

https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/29437

A SE employee could confirm my theory.

---

**Update:** Adam checked this out and fixed the issue as he commented:

> Looks like we have a bug in user deletion somewhere. I cleaned up the affected profiles. The underlying issue is now also fixed.

Comment: This was... 10 hours ago already, though....

Comment: Yeah, maybe some bug with the sync. The numbers don't seem to get through correctly.

Comment: Close, but not quite. Looks like we have a bug in user deletion somewhere. I cleaned up the affected profiles. The underlying issue is now also fixed.